# Is cudaFree() asynchronous?

Tags: cuda, gpu

My question is just as the title. Actually, I am looking for a way to free device memory asynchronously.

Thanks!

Comment: Better manage this memory yourself instead of doing it repeatedly in the pipeline code. cudaMalloc and cudaFree are slow!

Answer (score 8):

`cudaFree()` is synchronous.  If you really want it to be asynchronous, you can create your own CPU thread, give it a worker queue, and register `cudaFree` requests from your primary thread.

That said, asynchronous frees seem like an odd request.  Perhaps you could explain why you'd like it to be asynchronous.  Do you want the free to occur immediately after a CUDA event is triggered?

Comment: Frees of CUDA streams and CUDA events have been made asynchronous since their introduction, exactly because some applications have subroutines that use them, and there is a desire for those subroutines to not cause their callers' code paths to become synchronous.

Asynchronous frees is a totally reasonable request, for the same reason.  CUDA can asynchronously mark the memory as free, and if it must synchronize with the GPU to edit page tables, perform those operations lazily (wait until the next kernel thunk).

Comment: @Archaea: that's interesting.  I think the poster is also interested in freeing memory, not just the cudaEvent_t objects.  How does one associate a cudaFree with an event or stream?

Comment: Mr. Fooz, your answer is correct (i.e. AFAIK cudaFree() is synchronous), I am merely pointing out that it's reasonable to want it to be asynchronous.

Comment: Mr. Fooz. Thanks for your answer! My reason for asynchronous freeing memory is to make room for other streams so as to handle big problems, hope to get your advise: )

Comment: That makes sense.  Perhaps this would work: spawn a new CPU thread that calls cudaSetDevice, cudaDeviceSynchronize, then cudaFree (this probably doesn't work with pre-4.0 toolkits).

Answer (score 8):

Nine years later, there is a solution: CUDA 11.2 added `cudaFreeAsync` (together with `cudaMallocAsync`).

Answer (score 7):

cudaFree() is not asynchronous. A synchronization call is called internally when a cudaFree() is called from Host.

I didn't understand what actually your need for freeing memory asynchronously.

Comment: Imagine a pipeline of dependent kernel launches, some requiring temporary allocations. It'd be nice if the host thread could asynchronously insert `cudaMalloc`s and `cudaFree`s into such a pipeline.

Comment: In the case of big problem, you can use asynchronous freeing memory to make room for other streams. In other words, you will be able to handle big problems with many streams within a single GPU.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are **finding a reference on official docs**, it is written on the [CUDA Programming Guide :: **Appendix F. Stream Ordered Memory Allocator**](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#id64), the first line:

> Managing memory allocations using `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree` causes GPU to synchronize across all executing CUDA streams.